# Can't access related model when join is used in query - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to filter my **Agent** model by status. The status column is on a separate model, which is the **User**. So in my repository, this is how I do it:

```
public function blocked($howMany = 10)
{
    return $this->model->join('users', 'users.userable_id', '=', 'agents.id')
            ->where(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('users.status', config('user.status.blocked'));
            })
            ->paginate($howMany);
}
```

Where the value of **$this->model** is the Agent model instance injected in the constructor. Now, this code works, however, inside my loop in my controller:

```
public function blocked()
{
    $agents = $this->agents->blocked();

    foreach ($agents as $agent)
    {
        dd($agent->user);
    }

    return view('agents.admin', compact('agents'));
}
```

The value of **user** is null. What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally your relationship should be as follows:

```
public function blocked($howMany = 10)
{
    return $this->hasMany('users', 'userable_id', 'id')
                ->where('status','=',config('user.status.blocked'))
                ->paginate($howMany);
}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many